# how to avoid a clash of magnetic charge and electric charge

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, motors

now I'm working on a project which involves a dc motor and high voltage. I'm developing a machine consists of a motor to rotate a platform disc and high voltage will be applied during the rotation. The problem is when I supply a positive high voltage at motor shaft during rotation, the motor stop working. Do you guys have any idea, how I can supply the high voltage properly the high voltage supply?[image]

Comment: Of course it stops working! Do you supply the positive voltage to the other end of needle to spray something?

Comment: If you have collected magnetic charge, you win the Nobel Prize for the first magnetic monopoles!

Comment: @SamFarjamirad, yes I supply the positive high voltage to the end of needle to spray polymer solution. why is its stop working? can you explain to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't apply the high voltage to the motor shaft, isolate the disc and only apply the high voltage to that.

Edit based on comments:

isolate ie insulate, electrically separate the disc from the motor shaft while keeping the mechanical drive to make it rotate. Slip rings can be used to apply the voltage to the, now insulated, disc.

See here for an explanation of slip rings: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slip_ring

Comment: or slip ring...

Comment: hi, what do you mean by isolate the disc?

Comment: @SamFarjamirad what do you mean slip ring? thank you

Comment: @norul isolate ie insulate, electrically separate the disc from the motor shaft while keeping the mechanical drive to make it rotate.

Comment: @norul why it stops working, it's the very basics of electrometers, and i can't explain  it here in comments. You can google the term 'slip ring', then you'll find a tons of videos and articles.

Comment: @SolarMike the disc material is an insulator material. do I need to insulate it again? the disc is attached with the flange coupling and I connect it to the motor shaft. sorry, and thank you for the reply. I'm quite new in motor theory and still learning.

Comment: @SamFarjamirad the cause of its stop working is slip ring? . if  i want to supply the high voltage, formt he top is the best way? sorry, and thank you for the reply. I'm quite new in motor theory and still learning.

Comment: @norul 'the cause of its stop working is slip ring?' no that's not it. The slip ring is the solution for your problem. When you need to conduct a signal to a rotary device you use slip ring. 
When you supply positive voltage to the shaft, then you apply the voltage to both terminals of the motor so there would be no voltage across the brushes any more and it stops working.

Comment: @norul No, you need to isolate the MOTOR from the high voltage supply to the disc....

Comment: @SamFarjamirad, okay. I understand. I will search more about slip ring. Thank you so much. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @SolarMike okay, I understand it.  Thank you so much. I really appreciate ii too. Now i have idea what should i do.