# How to attach a cylindrical load to a motor safetly

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors

The project is to rotate a load using a motor with a varying speed between like *2000-10000 rpm*.

I'm using a **flange coupling** to attach the cylindrical tube to the motor. Since I will rotate it to high speed, I think I need to tightly and safely attach the load to the motor.

Do you have any suggestion on what coupling or what is the best way to attach the cylindrical tube to the motor **safely**?

NOTE: the shaft and load are the same lines. this machine is about centrifugal electrospinning which is a machine to fabricate a nanofiber.

[image]

Comment: Are there any special concerns for the coupling, such as does it need to be electrically isolated?

Comment: @SolarMike there is no special concern about it. but I'm not sure about it. should I insulate the cylindrical tube?

Comment: Just thought it may be linked to this project of yours : https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/23658/10902

Comment: @SolarMike yes it links to the project. just a different type of load.

Comment: Dont you have a machine shop around? I mean you should be able to build your design with a lathe. 3D Pinting this seems exceedingly unsafe.

Comment: @joojaa 3dprint is a trial, I will send to the factory once I got the right model based on my specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use the Flange Coupling with Key feature and Axis Support Fixed Seat.

Like this:

[image]

This design includes both. Also, one can find these off the shelf according to dimension requirements, or one can design one of them easily.

---

For example: [JoyceDayton](https://joycedayton.com/products/system-accessories/couplings)

[image]

For example: [Ebay](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/8mm-Flange-Coupling-Steel-Rigid-Flange-Coupling-Motor-Guide-Shaft-Axis-Bearing-F-/222683278447)

[image]

---

Most importantly, after the calculation of the bolt torques, one can use **lock tight** in order to make sure rigid connection.

Comment: thank you for the reply. for now, I'm using a flange coupling too. but I'm scared it will not safe.

Comment: @norul what can possibly happen ? Flange coupling are suitable for transmitting huge torque, if you tighten the bolt as stated in the manual it is probably not going to fail.

Comment: what is your main concern about safety? shear stress, buckling, power loss due to coupling, coupling fatigue, thermal limits... a little bit more info about the safety factor of the important component may lead to more detailed answer, I am waiting ! and last but not least, if you are going to fabricate fiber like this rotation, I strongly suggest you to use radial bearings[radial bearings](https://cdn.comsol.com/wordpress/2018/02/rotor-assembly-schematic.png)  to support the cylinder (shaft).

Comment: @SamFarjamirad. I just concern it will be detached while high-speed rotation. thank you for all the reply. I really appreciate it and so happy that you know what I'm doing.

Comment: @F.Bek, i just concern it will be detach while high speed rotation and i will search about the radial bearing in more ddetails .thank you so much for the reply.

Comment: @SamFarjamirad Re: "what can possibly happen?" - The assembly could vibrate dangerously and cause damage to the motor. A rigid coupling spinning at 10,000 rpm is not intrinsically safe, particularly with a non-cylindrical load such as that illustrated in the original post...

Answer (score 3):

The safest way to attach a non-symmetrical load (such as that shown in your photo) that spins that fast (up to 10,000rpm) will be to mount it  to a solid base, using bearings or similar, such that its weight is supported separately from the motor shaft. This will minimise vibrations/oscillations of the load.

As a result, there will now be a slight misalignment between the vibrating motor, and the constrained load. Using a a semi-flexible coupling (jaw, Oldham, etc) to transfer the rotation will accomodate this misalignment safely without damaging the motor.

Your biggest worry should be wobble from any off-centre mass of the load, rather than the direct strength of the coupling, per se.

Comment: and with those type of couplings, electrical separation may also be possible.

Comment: Jaw coupling is not flexible and Oldham here is not applicable since the shaft and load are centric.

Comment: @SamFarjamirad where is it stated about the support of the load - have you seen info about external centering bearings the rest of us missed?

Comment: @SolarMike Do you know what this machine designed for ? because i know, and i know the shaft  and the load are along the same line, so why Oldham coupling ? Do you see any radial deviation in OP's photo ? or that's only me who missed it ?

Comment: @SamFarjamirad then a complete answer here or for the other question that I have already linked to and the OP confirms is linked would save everbody’s time.

Comment: @SolarMike The complete answer is give by you (pervious question) and FBek here, I don't try to kill time, i just pointed it out the answer here above is incorrect. FYI this is called centrifugal electrospinning.

Comment: Anything spinning at 10,000rpm will vibrate/oscillate. In order to minimise the vibration of the load, it's a good idea to lock it down, using bearings etc, supporting it onto a fixed object. This will introduce a small amount of misalignment between the load and the motor which can be compensated for by a coupling. Oldham was mentioned as it's a well known example of a coupling that can accommodate some axial misalignment. They are not designed for non-concentric shafts, rather, concentric shafts that may be misaligned slightly during use, e.g. due to vibrations.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would use two grub screws at 90 degrees to each other, to secure the load onto the motor shaft. I have done this to attach a stainless steel flywheel on a motor spinning at 6,000 rpm and it's holding just fine.

To give it extra strength, you can also use something like Loctite 638 to glue the flange coupling, or whatever coupling you should choose, to the shaft. This probably means the coupling needs to be metal, not plastic (although I'm sure there'll be other glues to bong plastic to metal). Note that Loctite 638 is pretty much permanent: once you've glued your coupling onto the shaft, it won't be coming off again (easily).

Comment: thank you for the reply. in my case, I need to attach and detach the load since I will put some polymer solution in the cylindrical tank.